# Arrowhead won't appear

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, automata

I've drawn the following DFA but for some reason, the arrow connecting node 4 to node 3 will not show an arrowhead.
Interestingly, if I delete the edge at the other side from node 3 to node 4, the arrowhead then shows.

If anybody can shed some light then that would be great. I feel like it might be because I have tried to create the outer edges by brute force, and that there might be a more 'proper' way to do it.

I'd really appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{permute}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage[hmargin = 1.25 in, bmargin=1 in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows,calc}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\zerotext}[2][0pt]{\makebox[#1][l]{\qquad#2}}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\tikzset{
->, % makes the edges directed
>=stealth', % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state, accepting, initial ] (q1) {$1$};
\node[state, accepting, right of=q1] (q2) {$2$};
\node[state, accepting, above of=q2] (q3) {$3$};
\node[state, accepting, below of=q2] (q4) {$4$};
\node[state, accepting, right of=q2] (q5) {$5$};
%\tikzset{mystyle/.style={->,relative=false,in=0,out=0}}

\draw 
(q1) edge[bend left, left] node{$a$} (q3)
(q1) edge[above] node{$b$} (q2)
(q1) edge[bend right, left] node{$c$} (q4)

(q2) edge[above] node{$b$} (q5)
(q2) edge[bend left, left] node{$a$} (q3)
(q2) edge[bend left, right] node{$c$} (q4)
[->] (q4) to [out=180,in=-90] ($(q1)-(2,0)$) node at (-2.15,0) {$a$} to [out=90, in=180] (q3)
[->] (q3) to [out=0,in=90] ($(q5)+(2,0)$) node at (8.15,0) {$c$} to [out=-90, in=0] (q4)
(q3) edge[bend left, right] node{$b$} (q2)
(q3) edge[bend left, right] node{$a$} (q5)


(q4) edge[bend left, left] node{$b$} (q2)
(q4) edge[bend right, right] node{$c$} (q5)

(q5) edge[loop right, right] node{$a,b,c$} (q6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Changing arrow midway in a path it's dangerous and normally won't work. Try to put the two external arrows in a different `\draw ` command.

Comment: @Rmano thanks for the response. That's worked perfectly so thank you for that!

Answer (score 3):

One path has only one arrowhead, at the end. The graph works because the `->` thing is passed to `edge`, which creates a *different* path that is stroked at the end of the current one. So basically, remove the two lines starting with `[->]` (which is the default anyway) and add them at the end in a new path:

```latex
\draw 
(q1) edge[bend left, left] node{$a$} (q3)
(q1) edge[above] node{$b$} (q2)
(q1) edge[bend right, left] node{$c$} (q4)

(q2) edge[above] node{$b$} (q5)
(q2) edge[bend left, left] node{$a$} (q3)
(q2) edge[bend left, right] node{$c$} (q4)
(q3) edge[bend left, right] node{$b$} (q2)
(q3) edge[bend left, right] node{$a$} (q5)
(q4) edge[bend left, left] node{$b$} (q2)
(q4) edge[bend right, right] node{$c$} (q5)
(q5) edge[loop right, right] node{$a,b,c$} (q6);

\draw (q4) to [out=180,in=-90] ($(q1)-(2,0)$) node at (-2.15,0) {$a$} to [out=90, in=180] (q3);
\draw (q3) to [out=0,in=90] ($(q5)+(2,0)$) node at (8.15,0) {$c$} to [out=-90, in=0] (q4);
```

[image]

Comment: that's worked perfectly. Thankyou!!

Comment: ...I do not know why `(q6)` do not trigger an error here...